# How do I use JQuery in coordination with an anchor tag to move the screen to a location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I've never worked with this before so I am not sure if I apologize if I am using too many words to define what I am looking for.

I want to create a navigation menu in the header where upon clicking a link the screen should slowly move down to that section of the page.

Code structure:

```
 <div class="header">
      <a href="#about" class="link">About</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="link">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
       Some content
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
      About
  </div>
  <div class="section3">
      Contact
   </div>
```

So if a user clicked on About how do I use JQuery to slowly drag them to that section and the same for contact?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `id`'s on your `div` with the section name:

```
<div id='about' class="section2">
     About
</div>
```

Then use this code:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop' : $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}) //Will maybe be $(window) instead of html,body.
    return false;
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Hw4L6/

Comment: Thanks Karl.  But how do I add speed to it to slow it down?

Comment: If you look at [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) information page, you can see there is a duration parameter. Default is 400ms, you can do `$(el).animate({properties : values}, 1000)`. It will take 1 second to complete the animation!

Comment: ariel: Add a duration (in ms) as the second argument of the `animate` function: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I am new to JS so not sure where to put it? Do i put the $(el).animate({properties : values}, 1000) under     $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop' : $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}) //Will maybe be $(window) instead of html,body.
 ??

Comment: @ariel you don't need to add that line, you just need to add a comma and the duration after the last `}`

Comment: @koala_dev like this?   $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop' : $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 7000)
        return false;

Comment: @ariel yes exactly, there's just a `;` missing before the return statement

Comment: @koala_dev ok i did it but it's still the same speed. i am not sure what i am missing now?

Comment: @ariel I believe your jquery code is not working, do you see the page scrolling or jumping to each section? are you wrapping the code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});`?

Comment: @ariel is it possible to link your page or make a fiddle? PLus, is there any error in console?

Answer (score -1):

you could use jquery **scrollTo.js** script for smooth scrolling

or

you could just link to the section you want to scroll by just providing the id of the section in the **href** tag,like >>

```
<a href="#section2" class="link">About</a>
```

I have also used **scrollTo.js** in a small website I have written 2 years ago, here is the link ->

http://students.iitmandi.ac.in/~boga_saikiran/

there, when you click the **Contact Me** button on the top right or **Top** button on the bottom right you can see a smooth scrolling effect.

**The code related to it is >>**

(assuming you have jquery js file is included in your head tags)

1) download the scrollTo.js file and place it in your directory where your html file is

2) include this in the head tag

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='scrollTo.js'></script>
```

3) Place these in your javascript **script** tags inside the **head** tags

```
   $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $('#link_id').click(function(e)
         {
           $.scrollTo('#about','slow');
           e.preventDefault();
         });
    });
```

Comment: well this is just another way of doing,(providing knowledge that there are also other ways and libraries which are easy to use). @Karl-André Gagnon 's answer uses jQuerie's inbuilt animate function.